# Select an element without certain elements inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'd like to export my HTML div as a jpeg by clicking a button which is in the div and I don't want the button to be printed. Therefore I need a selector on the div which does not select items with a certain class inside the div.

I've tried the :not() selector, but it does not work appearantly:

```
$(".asdf:not(.export-button)")
```

Here is my code:

```
<div id="asdf">
    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    <img src="area_graph.png" alt="graph"/>
    <p>hallo</p>
    <button class="export-button">EXPORT</button>
</div>

$(".export-button").on("click", function () {

    var $tempNode = $(this).parent()[0];
    $tempNode.remove(".export-button");
    console.log($tempNode);

    // image export
});
```

Comment: Why just not setting display: none to the button?

Comment: why not clone the div `asdf` with out the button on a div that is hidden and use that div to make the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the DOM is a tree structure when you select one element you get all it's children with it. To do what you require you'd need to select the element then `remove()` the elements you do not want in a separate statement

```js
$(".export-button").on("click", function() {
  var $tempNode = $(this).parent().clone();
  $tempNode.find(".export-button").remove();
  console.log($tempNode.html());

  // image export
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="asdf">
  <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
  <img src="area_graph.png" alt="graph" />
  <p>hallo</p>
  <button class="export-button">EXPORT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: hide will work right instead of completely removing the button change the visibility to hide as if it is not there

Comment: @guradio that's possible too.

Comment: what if I need to select it out of the this element of the clicked div? The following code did not work for me:

    var $tempNode = $(this).parent()[0];
    $tempNode.remove(".export-button");

Comment: I would need to see your HTML to help you with that. Could you edit your question to include it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added my code to the question, I hope that helps

Comment: I updated the answer for you. The traversal on the `remove()` call was incorrect given your HTML.